# Best way to do a div with specific background-color?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a div with specific background-color depending on variable object.

My options are:

1. Create an infinite css for each color.
2. Style in-line.

I know style should be separated from html. But, in this case, what is more efficient?

Comment: Why not add a class to your div?

Comment: do it inline. css classes for each color is way too much.

Comment: Well... In the future, if in doubt, it is always less efficient to choose the option that requires doing something infinite times. Well, as a rule-of-thumb anyway.

(Also it's not exactly infinite, you'd only need 16,777,216. Minus one if you have a solid page background colour I suppose.)

Comment: @JBux That comment though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a different color based on dynamic content ("variable object")? In that case you should go for an inline-style. It would be easy for php/whatever backend you have to serve it conditionally.

While it's best to keep most styles on a stylesheet, there are exceptions to that rule. If your particular case asks for it, feel free to add your styles inline. For example, you need a gallery of things and you need the elements with a background-image instead of an img.

Answer (score 0):

**No, you cannot**. The options you provided are the only way... You can do a complex/advance `JavaScript`/`jQuery` but it will always boil down to on how you will provide the `selectors`.